# Can I use google analytics funnel to track signup process

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a funnel of the signup process (i.e. how many users bail out at each step).

However the numbers don't match up with the site statistics. I think the funnel is session based and not unique users based. And it also seems that a user can be counted multiple times.

What is the suggested way to get a funnel that simply tells me how many of the distinct users bail out at which step?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google Analytics supports user based funnels.

As an alternate you can create *sequential advance segments* to simulate user level funnel.

Example: 
Assuming your funnel has 3 steps (URLs), create 3 **user based segments** as below:

**Level 1:**
[image]

**Level 2:**
[image]

**Level 3:**
[image]

After creating the three segments, apply them to *Audience > Overview* report in the right order:

[image]

Although it doesn't provide you the percentage drops outright, you can calculate them manually.

Hope this helps.

NOTE: If your site receives high volumes of traffic, sampling can impact the results.